# AngularJS, twitter api's rate limit and security

Tags: angularjs, cordova, twitter

I'm developing an application in Cordova with AngularJS.. I'm trying to get a users feed and put the tweets with images in a slider/carousel. The carousel already works fine, but there comes the twitter api...

I was thinking about the twitter rate limit, if the app is downloaded for multiple users, the application won't be able to make more requests for a while. On the other hand, if I use the consumer key, secret and access token inside the application, it's probably that is easy for anyone to use them. So it can be insecure.

I was thinking about a little web service that takes twitter content every X minutes from twitter and save that content somewhere, so the application can access the content from the little web service. Is this plausible?

I've been messing around with this... but I don't see how... An embedded timeline wouldn't be a solution because I need a custom slider only for tweets with images..

Thanks for any help you can give me

My best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to make users authenticate with their twitter, then store the results you grab in some form of local storage. That way you don't have to share an api key between users, and when they make a call, it will store for x amount of time.